# Programmatically Compare Microsoft Office Files

Tags: c#, python, office-interop, pywin32

I am looking for the easiest way to see if two Office files have the same *content* using Python. My first instinct is to use `filecmp.cmp`, but this approach logically fails, since two files do not necessarily contain the same binary information even if they have the same content.

```
In [10]: import win32com.client

In [11]: word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

In [12]: doc = word.Documents.Add()

In [13]: doc.SaveAs(FileName = "test.docx")

In [14]: doc.SaveAs(FileName = "test2.docx")

In [15]: import filecmp

In [16]: filecmp.cmp("test.docx","test2.docx")
Out[16]: False
```

Next, I could try to compare the content of files manually like so:

```
def compareWordDocs(self, worddoc1_path, worddoc2_path):

    worddoc1 = self._wordapp.Documents.Open(FileName = worddoc1_path)
    worddoc2 = self._wordapp.Documents.Open(FileName = worddoc2_path)

    worddoc1_content_text = worddoc1.Content.Text
    worddoc2_content_text = worddoc2.Content.Text

    worddoc1.Close(SaveChanges = 0)
    worddoc2.Close(SaveChanges = 0)

    return worddoc1_content_text == worddoc2_content_text
```

However, this also can be an issue since Office documents can contain many things besides text. Does Microsoft offer any functionality that will let me do something like a `__eq__()` or a `.equals()` function, with which equality of content can be determined? I would need a solution for as many Microsoft Office products as possible, although I realize that the solution may vary from product to product given the nature of the files.

Comment: What is your definition of *content*? Images? Formatting? Tables? Whitespace? Headers?

Comment: Quite honestly unless you're comparing hundreds of documents I would use Word's built-in comparison tool.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html ?

Comment: @Lattyware Good question. By content, I mean what the user sees when they open a file in the appropriate program. However, I would be willing to take shortcuts, such as simply verifying there is an image of the same size in the same place in two 'equivalent' office files.

Comment: @KronoS I am comparing hundreds of word documents. I need to verify that content is saved correctly by office programs (through the native SaveAs method) to a server in a test harness, so I need to compare the local content with the remote content.

Comment: @julien-palard Thank you for this suggestion. I have tried this a little, but I am unsure how to verify that two documents are the same with it. Just parse the results making sure no strings begin with '-' or '+'? Also, is it able to handle binary sequences like what would be in .doc files?